Is it safe to keep the Garuda Purana in home?
I've heard elsewhere that one should not keep a physical book (of the Garuda Purana) inside homes. Is this true? What happens if one keeps it?

Part of Garuda Purana is read during Shraddha (last rite). It contains a vivid description of what happens after the soul departs from the body and its journey in the afterlife. I guess, as this Purana is so much related to death people are scared to keep it at home. It is just my conjecture.

I have had a copy of Garuda Purana for probably 10 years. I am still around.
